# JProfiler call stack splitting

Tags: java, jprofiler

I'm using call stack splitting to analyze individual method calls and parameters passed. However, I keep running into the splitting cap limit, at which point the calls get merged together, and there is an option to "reset splitting cap counter".

This is useless, because reloading the tree runs into the same splitting cap limit and does exactly the same merging again.

How do I increase the splitting cap? From the documentation, it says I can do this from the Profiler Settings, but I cannot find any setting in any section called "splitting cap" or anything similar.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think additional info would not be redundant: JProfiler version, Java version, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is a setting on the "CPU profiling settings" step in the session settings dialog:

[image]

We'll improve the tool tip help in the next bugfix release.